# How to build new instance of Value object from existng one with updated collection property using Lombok Builder?

Tags: java, lombok

I'm using immutable objects with a collection property. Something like this:

```
@Value
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
class Person {

    String name;
    @Singular
    Set<String> skills;

}
```

When I create a new instance of Person from existing one but with updated skills it seems that collecction is not updated.

```
        Person jonh = Person.builder()
                .name("John")
                .build();
        System.out.println(jonh);

        Person johnUpgraded = jonh.toBuilder()
                .skill("Java")
                .skill("Spring")
                .build();
        System.out.println(johnUpgraded);

        Person johnDowngraded = johnUpgraded.toBuilder()
                .skills(Collections.emptySet())
                .build();
        System.out.println(johnDowngraded);
```

It prints:

```
Person(name=John, skills=[])
Person(name=John, skills=[Java, Spring])
Person(name=John, skills=[Java, Spring])
```

Is it possible to create a copy of person and set other skills?

Many thanks for considering my request!

Is it possible to create a copy of person and set other skills?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this cleanly with a `@With`-er. This annotation generates a `with` method that is similar to a setter, but it will return a new instance of the object. In my opinion this is the way to go for immutable objects:

```
import lombok.With;

@Value
@Builder
static class Person {
    String name;
    @With
    @Singular
    Set<String> skills;
}

@Test
void test() {
    Person jonh = Person.builder()
            .name("John")
            .build();
    System.out.println(jonh);

    Person johnUpgraded = jonh.withSkills(Set.of(
            "Java",
            "Spring"
    ));
    System.out.println(johnUpgraded);
}
```

Comment: Well done. So, it creates deep copy and replaces `skills`?

Comment: can we do the same thing with multiple fields?

Comment: yes, you can add `@With` for multiple fields or at the class level (if you want to apply it to all of them). here is the documentation for it: https://projectlombok.org/features/With

Comment: Thank you very much! @With annotation solves the problem)

Answer (score 0):

You can call `clearSkills()` first to completely reset the contents of that collection. Otherwise all values remain; with `@Singular` all setter methods act like "adders".

Comment: Thank you very much! clearSkils().skills(<a new set of skills>) is another good solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your `.skills(Collections.emptySet())` method just adds empty set on top of existing one.

If you want to clear it just use `clear() method:

```java
//to make it work, add @Getter annotation on top of your Person class
johnUpgraded.getSkills().clear();
```

> Is it possible to create a copy of person...

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56808295/10109156) `toBuilder()` method doesn't do deep copy. So `jonh`, `johnUpgraded` and `johnDowngraded` are the same object.

To make copy of your object you have to use `Person.builder()` again, like this:

```java
        Person jonh = Person.builder()
                .name("John")
                .build();

        Person johnUpgraded = Person.builder()
                .name(jonh.getName()) 
                .skill("Java")
                .skill("Spring")
                .build();
```

---

Update:

To [clone your Set](https://www.baeldung.com/java-copy-sets#copyConstructor), create another one based on previous one.

```
.skill(new HashSet<>(jonh.getSkills()));
```

Comment: In fact, lombok's `toBuilder()` _does_ a (shallow) copy of `@Singular` collections. I.e., the set in the to-be-created `Person` instance will be a new set. There is no need to manually clone the `skills` set.